# Find the most occurrences of a list and return a list starting with the most occurrent ele

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun occurrences (l)
(let (
        (result (mapcar #'(lambda (elt) (cons elt (count elt l)) ) 
            (remove-duplicates l)   )   )
        (result2 nil)  
        (result3 nil)
        (result4 nil)
    )
(progn
    (sort result #'> :key #'cdr)
    (loop for x in result
        do (and(push (car x) result2)(push (cdr x) result3))
    )
)))
```

This should return a sorted list occurrences in ascending order. With the exception that the elements that repeat a minimum number of times (in contract with the rest of the list) should not be returned. Unless all the elements repeat equal number of times, then only in this situation all the elements get returned.

For instance,

1. ( occurrences '(1 2 3)) => (1 2 3), #notice each element repeats same # of times.
2. ( occurrences '(1 1 3)) => (1) #since there 1 occurs more frequently than any other element in the list.

3 ( occurrences '(1 2 3 4 6 6 6 6)) => (6)

4. ( occurrences '(1 1 3 3 0)) => (1, 3). #since (1 2), (3 2) and (0 1)
   Because the occurrences of elements 1 and 3 are still higher than at least one element's occurrence in such list.

Note: Right now this function returns a sorted list, but incorrectly returns max values (number of occ.) plus elements, which occurrences, are not at least larger than one other element in the list.
Ex. 
(occurrences '(7 7 7 1 2 3)) returns (7 1 2 3) but should only return 7. I would really appreciate the some help fixing this function to return whats expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that uses your initial approach is the following:

```
(defun max-occurrences(l)
  (let* ((occurrences (remove-duplicates 
                        (mapcar #'(lambda (elt) (cons elt (count elt l))) l) 
                        :test 'equal))
         (max-occurrence (reduce #'max occurrences :initial-value 0 :key #'cdr)))
    (mapcar #'car (remove-if-not (lambda(x) (= x max-occurrence)) occurrences :key #'cdr))))
```

However, this solution is not efficient, since it has a cost of O(n<sup>2</sup>) (in the initial phase, each element of the list is compared with all the others to count its frequency).

*Edited*

A more efficient solution could be obtained for instance by using a hash table (with the improvement suggested in the comment by @uselpa):

```
(defun max-occurrences(l)
   (let* ((table (make-hash-table))
          (max-count (loop for elt in l maximize (incf (gethash elt table 0)))))
     (loop for elt being the hash-key of table using (hash-value count)
        when (= count max-count) collect elt)))
```

Comment: You can save one pass with `(let ((max-count  (loop for elt in l maximize (incf (gethash elt table 0)))))`

Comment: @uselpa, this is a really elegant, thanks! I have updated the answer.